# Why I'm getting Warning(453) Cant apply (char *STRING, int LENGTH) no typemaps are defined

Tags: java, c, swig

I'm trying to call c function from java code.
I'm using swig (ver 1.3.40) and running under ubunto.

my interface file looks:

```
%module test
%include "typemaps.i"
%apply(char *STRING, int LENGTH) {(char* pchInput, int inputSize)};
%{
#include "example.h"
%}
void testFunc(char* pchInput, int inputSize);
```

I'm getting the following wanning/error:
warning(453): Cant apply (char *STRING,int LENGTH). No typemaps are defined.

The following links doesnt help me:

[SWIG: Warning 453: Can't apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24012753/swig-warning-453-cant-apply-char-string-size-t-length-no-typemaps-are-def)

[SWIG: No typemaps are defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763882/swig-no-typemaps-are-defined)

[Swig typemap java object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26110908/swig-typemap-java-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange.

I tried your above example with the current swig 3.0.7 (calling it test.i and using `swig -java test.i`) and it works fine. Also, you don't need to `%include "typemaps.i"` for this to work. However as far as I can tell this should also work with (ancient) swig 1.3.40.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply your typemap before including the header using %include and you should start with the regular #include

```
%module test
%{
  #include "example.h"
%}
%include "typemaps.i"
%apply(char *STRING, int LENGTH) {(char* pchInput, int inputSize)};
%include "example.h"
```

where example.h contain your function declaration. Try this

Comment: You shouldn't use `#include "example.h"` at all, but `%{ #include "example.h" %}` as user3668129 did. The `%apply` needs to come before the declaration in swig (either `%include "example.h"` or `void testFunc(char* pchInput, int inputSize);`), but this is also already the case in the question.

Comment: The `%apply` must come before the `%include "example.h"`. To have the naked function declaration unquoted with `%` at the end of the interface is not the typical use.

Comment: The [swig docs](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIG_nn3) state that the version in the question of user3668129 is "the most common format".